# Why is Markov's Principle an axiom?

Tags: logic, axioms, philosophy, constructive-mathematics

Markov's Principle: Let $ x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then the following holds:
\begin{align*}
\neg (x = 0) \Longrightarrow \vert x \vert >0.
\end{align*}

In constructive mathematics (no law of excluded middle) this is viewed as an axiom, which follows from the Limited Principle of Omniscience.

But isn't there also a constructive proof for the MP?
For example, in my opinion the following holds:

\begin{align*}
\neg (x = 0 ) \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{x} x = 1 \Longrightarrow \vert \frac{1}{x} x \vert = \vert  1 \vert > 0 \Longrightarrow \vert \frac{1}{x} \vert > 0 \wedge \vert x \vert > 0.
\end{align*}

Moreover, for $\neg (x=0)$ let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then we either have (by approximate splitting)
\begin{align*}
\vert x \vert > \frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}
or 
\begin{align*}
\vert x \vert < \frac{1}{2n}.
\end{align*}

In the first case, MP holds. In the latter case, letting $ n \longrightarrow \infty$, yields $\vert x \vert = 0$, hence $x = 0$ which is a contradiction.

Obviously my "proof" has to be wrong at some point, but I don't see where.

Comment: What is your definition of $|\cdot|$?

Comment: @Matthew Leingang absolute value of a real number. Probably something like $\sqrt (x^2)$, but in my text there is no explicit definition.

Comment: The issue is probably with the ">" relation - I suppose that in this situation $a > 0$ means there is a rational $q$ with $a > q > 0$.  It's not hard to imagine a situation where $ab = 1$ but we don't know that $|a| > 0$ because we don't have any sense of when the approximations for $a$ will reveal that $a \not = 0$.

Comment: Perhaps it helps to look at the alternative form of Markov's principle: $[\lnot (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}) \lnot P(n) ] \to (\exists n \in \mathbb{N}) P(n)$ where $P(n)$ is a decidable predicate.   Here, for example, $P(n)$ would say that we can tell from the $n$th approximation of $x$ that $x \not = 0$.  I think that the limit in your argument is just hiding the application of Markov's principle: the argument seems to be that, because the limit of something can't be zero, we can find a step when the limit is guaranteed to be nonzero.

Comment: @Carl I was taught, that constructively the following holds: $\vert a b \vert > 0 \Longrightarrow \vert a \vert > 0 \wedge \vert b \vert > 0$.

I am not really familiar with the basic formulation of MP. It is maybe true, that MP is hiding somewhere in the limit. But what about the first attempt?

Comment: So which properties of absolute value are you taking as axiomatic?

Comment: @Matthew Leingang To be honest, I think none.

Comment: OK, then I think the question is not really well-posed.  It seems you're asking if MP is truly necessary as an axiom, or can it be derived from other properties.  The problem is *which other properties*.  It could be one of the properties you use relies on something equivalent to MP.  The ground rules (other axioms/properties) have to be established, otherwise you risk circular logic.

Comment: @Matthew Leingang This might be the case. I tried to use the real numbers as defined in Techniques of Constructive Analysis by Douglas Bridges. 

I think the major problem is the implication $\vert x y \vert > 0 \Longrightarrow \vert y \vert > 0 \wedge \vert x \vert > 0$. I have seen many authors using it as a constructive tool, but it might be true that MP is needed in order to show this.

Comment: I just thought about this implication for a bit and I think it is enough to use approximate splitting: Let $\vert x y \vert > 0$. To show $\vert x \vert > 0$ and $\vert y \vert > 0$. Firstly, $\vert x \vert > 0$. Let $\epsilon > 0$, with approximate splitting I get two cases:

Case1:  $\vert x \vert > \epsilon/2$; whence nothing to show.

Case2: $\vert x \vert < \epsilon$, then $0 < \vert x y \vert = \vert x \vert \vert y\vert < \epsilon \vert y \vert \Longrightarrow 0 < \vert y \vert \Longrightarrow 0 < \vert x \vert$, since I think I am able (allowed) to divide with positive numbers.

Comment: @Diamir But you don't *yet* know the absolute value of anything-but-zero is a positive number when that is what you utimately seek *to prove*.  You cannot accept something as a proven fact inside a proof of itself.  All you have shown is $$\lvert xy\rvert>0 \to (\lvert x\rvert >0 \to \lvert y\rvert >0)$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp I don't get what you mean. In my opinion i did show $\vert x y \vert > 0 \Longrightarrow \vert x \vert > 0$. The proof of $\vert x y \vert > 0 \Longrightarrow \vert y \vert > 0$ would be analogously.

Comment: @Diamir You have asserted $\epsilon>0$, but why not let $\epsilon<0$?

Comment: @GrahamKemp I see what you mean. But I don't think this matters here. I just took any $\epsilon > 0$, which is no problem, and then used approximate splitting. I think it is possible to assume that there exist real numbers > 0. I don't see a reason why I need also the distinction $\epsilon < 0$.

Comment: @Diamir Because $\lvert x\rvert <0\to (\lvert x y\rvert >0\to\lvert y\rvert <0)$

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your "proof" is the use of $\frac{1}{x}$. What [notion of field](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/field#constructive) are you using?

If you are using a discrete field, then it is justified. But since the reals aren't a discrete field, you probably aren't.

If you are using a Heyting field or weaker, then you can only talk about the inverse if you can establish that $x$ is [*apart*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/apartness+relation) from $0$, which is most likely equivalent to $|x|>0$. Likely another way of reformulating this variant of MP is $\neg(x=0)\implies x\# 0$ using $\#$ for apartness.

Comment: I was following the book Techniques of Constructive Analysis
by Douglas Bridges and Luminiţa Simona Vîţă. They didn't mention the notion of a field as far as I am concerned. They also used this kind of proof a lot; i.e considered the cases $\vert u \vert < \varepsilon$ and $\vert u \vert \neq 0$ in order to show something by approximate splitting. In the latter case, they didn't seem to hesitate to divide by $\vert u \vert$ without mentioning any use of additional axiom/theorem. \\

So is the the MP constructively provable in a discrete field?

Comment: A discrete field is a Heyting field so invertibility is equivalent to being apart from $0$. In a discrete field, we can prove $x$ is invertible if $\neg(x=0)$, thus $\neg(x=0)\implies x\# 0$ and Markov's Principle holds at least in the variant I mentioned. However, a residue/Heyting field that is a discrete field has decidable equality which is where the name "discrete" comes from. It would be a rare constructivist that viewed decidable equality for any reasonable definition of "reals" as constructive.